# How many digits are there in $5^{1389}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many digits are there in $5^{1389}$? (Without using the logarithm)

---

my try :

$$5^{1389}=\left(\frac{10}{2}\right)^{1389}=10^{1389}\times 2^{-(1389)}$$

now what ?:(

Comment: Why do you say "without use log"?

Comment: @ChrisCulter .Without using the logarithm

Comment: Why don't you want to use the logarithm?

Comment: @ChrisCulter Assuming the question.

Comment: Do you need the exact answer or an order of magnitude ?

Comment: Hint : to show how much big is $2^{64}$ without log  , we can do this $$2^{10}=1024\sim1000\\
2^{20}=(2^{10})^2\sim1000^2 \sim 10 ^6$$ and so on  ...
  
may be help you

Comment: The you can split $5^{1389}$ by doing for example $5^{1388} \times 5$ and we know that $5$ has 1 digit. Then $5^{1387} \times 5^2$ and we know that $5^2$ being $25$ has two digits. So $5^{1389}$ has more than $2$ digits. Keep going until you have $5^m \times 5^n$ where ideally you want that $m = n$ and after having counted the digits, there you go. Unfortunately $1389$ is odd so you won't have $m = n$. That is a long way, but that is the only "logarithm" as of all I know of finding the amount of digits. Otherwise, go on the Million Digit Comptune Calculator and do what I did in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is difficult to answer without using $\log$. Of course, if you have a calculator that can handle sufficiently large numbers, you can calculate that $5^{1389} \approx 7.4 \cdot 10^{970}$, then you know that there are $971$ digits in this number. If the problem is that you can't calculate this number, but you can use $\log$ (just not on the original number), you can note that $\log(5^{1389}) = 1389 \log(5)$, which is something you should be able to calculate with a normal calculator.

Otherwise, you have nothing left but approximating $2^{1389}$ as a power of ten.

It is quite well-known that $2^{10} = 1024 > 10^3$. I also try to remember that $2^{299} > 10^{90}$. Then we have $2^{1389} = 2^{4.5\cdot 299 + 43.5} > 8\sqrt{2} \cdot 10^{4.5 \cdot 90 + 3 \cdot 4} = 8\sqrt{2} \cdot 10^{417} > 10^{418}$.

On the other hand, these estimates are all reasonably tight, so you can also show that $10^{419} > 2^{1389}$, so $10^{971} = \frac{10^{1389}}{10^{418}} > 5^{1389} > \frac{10^{1389}}{10^{419}} = 10^{970}$, so there are $971$ digits.